# Select last inserted ten rows

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework. I want to get recently inserted (means last ten) ten rows. The table `User` has two columns:

```
userID
password
DateTime
```

How can I get most recent ten rows?

Comment: Unless you additionally have some kind of a `DateAdded` column of type `DATE` or `DATETIME`, this cannot be done. Or is the `UserID` an ever-increasing (e.g. `INT IDENTITY`) column?

Comment: I have added DateTime column. please review it.

Comment: I just hope this column isn't really called `DateTime` - that would be the worst possible name for that column....

Answer (score 6):

If you have a `DateTime` (or `DATE`) column then you can use something like this:

```
using(YourDbContext ctx = new YourDbContext())
{
   var lastTenRows = ctx.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.DateTimeColumn).Take(10).ToList();
}
```